# Declaring income made in a foreign country

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india

I was in the US from 2010 - July, 2016. In July I moved back to my home country (India) and have been working here ever since. I still count as a resident alien for 2016 in the US for tax purposes (note: I'm NOT a US citizen. I was in the US on a F1 + OPT)

Do I need to declare the income I made from Aug-Dec in my home country on my US tax returns? As far as I can tell, I *do* need to but I don't need to pay any taxes on it because of the Double Taxation Avoidance Agreement between India and US.

Is that right?